# How to calcluate MAX on measure in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax

How to calculate MAX if I already have a Average measure of a Price?

I have tried `Top price =MAX([Average Selling Price])`

any help?

Comment: Is javascript useful for you? I know the solution in it very well regarding this question

Comment: Add your sample input data with your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a Date table and you desire the maximum average selling price per day, you can use MAXX like follows

```
MAXX( 'Date', [Average Selling Price] )
```

Of course a different table, or table function, can be used instead of 'Date', depending on what the average is applied. If, for instance, you have a Product table with a Category column, and you want the maximum average selling price per product category, you can write

```
MAXX( ALL( 'Product'[Category] ), [Average Selling Price] )
```

or

```
MAXX( VALUES( 'Product'[Category] ), [Average Selling Price] )
```

depending on how you want to use the current filter context over Product table.